# Why is the first random number always the same on some platforms in lua?

Tags: random, lua

Consider the following lua code snippet :

```
local time = os.time()
for _= 1, 10 do
    time = time + 1
    print('Seeding with ' .. time)
    math.randomseed(time)
    for i = 1, 5 do
        print('\t' .. math.random(100))
    end
end
```

On a Linux machine, the result is, as expected, random numbers. But it seems that at least on Mac OS X, the first random number after changing the seed is always the same !

I guess this is related to the fact that Lua relies on the C rand() function for generating random numbers, but does anybody have an explanation ?

EDIT: here is an extract of the output of the above code on a linux machine (ie the output is as expected) :

```
$ lua test.lua
Seeding with 1232472273
    69
    30
    83
    59
    84
Seeding with 1232472274
    5
    21
    63
    91
    27
[...]
```

On an OS X machine, the first number after "Seeding with ..." was always 66.

Comment: Do you use the same lua versions on both machines? Perhaps a bug in the Mac OS X one.

Comment: Yes, I use the latest lua version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua's random used to use C's `rand(3)` and `srand(3)` functions ([see here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lmathlib.c.html#math_random)). UPDATE: newer Lua versions [use random(3) where available](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lmathlib.c.html#l_rand).

Both the C90 standard and POSIX suggest an cross-platform implementation of `rand` and `srand` that isn't the best. It especially lacks randomness in the lower bits.

Some platforms like Linux moved off of the standard recommendation to a better implementation (e.g. [random(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/random)).

OS/X remains true to the classic `rand` implementation, and Lua inherits it.

Comment: That still doesn't really explain why he's always getting 66 as the first number back, but it is good information.

Comment: That the algorithm "isn't the best" is quite an understatement ;) It doesn't do what it should and is completely useless and broken. And no, you cannot argue that "your shouldn't use it like this", programmers should not be required to have this knowledge.

Comment: None of the C standards, including C90, define any sort of implementation for `rand` or `srand`.  They simply specify what the functions are supposed to do (return pseudo-random numbers).  The standards do include an example implementation, but examples are not normative in ISO standards---they impose no constraints.  Implementations of C are allowed to use whatever versions of `rand` and `srand` they want, and using definitions other than the example are definitely not "non-conforming".  I suggest you change your wording :)  (E.g., [C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.10.2)).

Comment: @ChuckyEllison fair enough!

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad idea to call srand multiple times with seeds that are numerically close (and especially bad to do so with time values). In many cases, the variance of the first random number is similar to the variance of the seeds. When dealing with a scripting language that has to convert number representations, it can be even more so.

Does the same thing occur if you change your seed value by a larger amount?

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, Lua intentionally uses C90 random generator for portability sake -- and C90 RNG is not very good.

If you need good random numbers, use some Lua module to get it. For example, [here](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lrandom) is Mersenne Twister RNG binding by one of Lua authors.