# Generating uniform random numbers in Lua

Tags: random, lua, random-seed

I am working on programming a Markov chain in Lua, and one element of this requires me to uniformly generate random numbers. Here is a simplified example to illustrate my question:

```
example = function(x)
    local r = math.random(1,10)
    print(r)
    return x[r]
end

exampleArray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"}

print(example(exampleArray))
```

My issue is that when I re-run this program multiple times the exact same random number is generated resulting in the example function selecting the exact same array element. However, if I include many calls to the example function within the single program by repeating the print line at the end many times I get suitable random results.

This is not my intention as a proper Markov pseudo-random text generator should be able to run the same program with the same inputs multiple times and output different pseudo-random text every time. I have tried resetting the seed using `math.randomseed(os.time())` and this makes it so the random number distribution is no longer uniform. My goal is to be able to re-run the above program and receive a randomly selected number every time.

Comment: Seed the generator *once*.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Weird thing is after seeding the generator (once!) the first call to math.random always returns the same value. After that though all subsequent calls return the randomness I was looking for. I just have one "junk" call before I start using the numbers returned by math.random. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: That's expected output for the Mersenne twister implemented in some C standard library implementations: the first value will drift slightly depending on the difference of the seed, then the second value will drift more, and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the first random number always the same on some platforms in lua?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461978/why-is-the-first-random-number-always-the-same-on-some-platforms-in-lua)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to run `math.randomseed()` **once** before using `math.random()`, like this:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

From your comment that you saw the first number is still the same. This is caused by the implementation of random generator in some platforms.

The solution is to pop some random numbers before using them for real:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
math.random(); math.random(); math.random()
```

Note that the standard C library `random()` is usually not so uniformly random, a better solution is to use a better random generator if your platform provides one.

Reference: [Lua Math Library](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial)

Answer (score 13):

Standard C random numbers generator used in Lua isn't guananteed to be good for simulation. The words "Markov chain" suggest that you may need a better one. Here's a generator widely used for Monte-Carlo calculations:

```
local A1, A2 = 727595, 798405  -- 5^17=D20*A1+A2
local D20, D40 = 1048576, 1099511627776  -- 2^20, 2^40
local X1, X2 = 0, 1
function rand()
    local U = X2*A2
    local V = (X1*A2 + X2*A1) % D20
    V = (V*D20 + U) % D40
    X1 = math.floor(V/D20)
    X2 = V - X1*D20
    return V/D40
end
```

It generates a number between 0 and 1, so `r = math.floor(rand()*10) + 1` would go into your example.
(That's multiplicative random number generator with period 2^38, multiplier 5^17 and modulo 2^40, original Pascal code by http://osmf.sscc.ru/~smp/)

Comment: This will, however, always produce the same sequence of numbers. It isn't clear how one would "seed" the procedure (by changing the initial value of `X1` and `X2` for example) without the degradation of the period.

Comment: To have a different sequence you need to set X1 and X2 to different numbers.
0 <= X1 <= 2^20-1,
1 <= X2 <= 2^20-1 (must be odd!)
Also, the algorithm can be optimized a lot, especially with 64-bit unsigned integers.

Comment: Basically, in LuaJIT rand() boils down to this: X1 = X1*762939453125ull; return tonumber(X1)*(2.0^-64). Initial X1 is 0ull + (Seed*2 + 1) * 2^24, where 0 <= Seed <= 2^39-1.

Answer (score 12):

```
math.randomseed(os.clock()*100000000000)
for i=1,3 do
    math.random(10000, 65000)
end
```

Always results in new random numbers. Changing the seed value will ensure randomness. Don't follow `os.time()` because it is the epoch time and changes after one second but `os.clock()` won't have the same value at any close instance.

Answer (score 2):

There's the Luaossl library solution: (https://github.com/wahern/luaossl)

```
local rand = require "openssl.rand"
local randominteger
if rand.ready() then -- rand has been properly seeded
    -- Returns a cryptographically strong uniform random integer in the interval [0, n−1].
    randominteger = rand.uniform(99) + 1 -- randomizes an integer from range 1 to 100
end
```

http://25thandclement.com/~william/projects/luaossl.pdf