# Lua math.random?

Tags: random, lua, random-seed

I've been having trouble generating a random number for a while now using Lua.  I tried starting the script with math.randomseed(os.time()) and I was still getting the same results.  How would I get the script below to generate a new random number every time I run the script?

```
function rand()
local x = math.random(1, #Questions) --Pick a random question from a table
return x
end
```

Comment: Pop some random numbers after `math.randomseed(os.time())`, see the answer to the duplicate of your previous question [Generating uniform random numbers in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20157671/1009479) carefully. If that's not working, post more information, like ``#Questions` and what you got, etc.

Comment: Yu Hao, you should put this as an answer instead of a comment - I think it is exactly what he is asking for - so it can be accepted (and you get the internet points!)

Comment: @starmole I guess it's the reason, but there's not enough information. And if it really is, it's better to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [well known problem](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-03/msg00564.html). Just call `math.random` once or twice before using the result in your program.

Comment: Or propagate low bit changes to high bits by `math.randomseed((''..os.time()):reverse())`