# Can we limit the scope of srand

Tags: c++, lua, random-seed

we are in the context of a lua script which uses some C/C++ functions exported to be used with lua.

In lua, we have

```
math.randomseed(12) // 12 for example
for i=0, 10 do
    c++function()
    print(math.random())
end
```

the output is always the same number.
When i saw the cause, i found that in the c++_function, there is an srand(0) and some calls to the rand() function.

So our math.randomseed(12) will have no effect, and we will in each iteration have srand(0), the rand() call, and after that the math.random() call(which just call the C rand() function).
and because we are giving always the same seed, we have always the same sequence generated.

The question is, is there a solution to make srand(x) limited to a specific scope ? so the rand() call in c++_function will use the seed 0, and when we return back to lua, the math.random() uses the math.randomseed(x).

If no, any one have a suggestion ?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you change the c++ function? `srand()` should be called only once for the whole program.

Comment: No, because the c++ function call is independant from the lua script, the problem is caused only in this example, because both of them did srand. in another lua script, we can call the c++_function without math.randomseed in lua.

Comment: If you can't change either of `math.randomseed` and `c++function`, I'm afraid you're out of luck...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `srand` does not return its current seed. Nevertheless, you can fake it. Try this:

```
function call_c_function()
    local s=math.random(1,2^30)
    c++function()
    math.randomseed(s)
end

for i=0, 10 do
    call_c_function()
    print(math.random())
end
```

Just make sure that you *don't* call `math.randomseed` before each call to `math.random`, but only after calling `c++function`, as above.

Comment: Thx.this will work, but the modification should be in c++ code. we deliver our c++ code to be used in lua scripts by the client. So, i can't act on the choices in their lua files.
i saw the code, and , in my opinion, i can delete srand from the c++ function, i made a suggestion and i wait for answer. this will resolve the problem :)

Comment: @ahmedbouchaala, you can always distribute a tiny Lua file that wraps as above the functions that mess with `srand`. But avoid the mess in the first place is the way to go: `srand` is supposed to be called only once in a program.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will not be able to limit the scope of srand() to affect only your invocation of math.random().

I'd suggest to use a random number generator that is independent of the built-in. See [Generating uniform random numbers in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154991/generating-uniform-random-numbers-in-lua) for an example.